# can't reference global variable inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day to all.
I am trying to build a game called 2048.I made a variable named box and added 4 lists each list containing a 4 empty values to be replaced later.Then I declared it global(tried reverse too:declared global and then made the values inside them).when I call global box in one function(to do changes to the box),it works.then I called another function which changes position of box and it too passed without a error.but the third where I assign the box to another variable with list comphrehension like this:

```
box = [[[]]*4 for i in range(4)] # this is box
box1 = [box[i][::-1] for i in range(4)] # tried to do this
```

the second function didn't require box1 but I called it to see if any error occurs.Nothing occurs.
but when I do same with the next function error "NameError:free variable box referenced before assignment in enclosing scope" occurs.

why is that.what did I do wrong?
here is the code

```
import random
global box
box = [[[]]*4 for i in range(4)]


def adding():
    digit = random.choice([2,4])
    empty = [index for index,i in enumerate(box[0]) if i==[]]
    add = random.choice(empty)
    try:
        for i in range(3):
            if box[i][add] == [] and box[i+1][add] != []:
                box[i][add] = digit
                break
            elif box[-1][add] == []:
                box[-1][add] = digit
                break
    except:
        print('Error Occured')

def right():
    box1=[box[i][::-1] for i in range(4)]
    for i in range(4):
        take = box[i]
        box[i]=[[] for x in take if x ==[]]
        for j in [x for x in take if x != []]:
            box[i].append(j)

def left():
    box1 = [box[i][::-1] for i in range(4)]
    right()
    box1 = [box[i][::-1] for i in range(4)]
    box= box1
```

error occurs at function `left()`
tried in different os too.

thanks.works when I declared global inside function but ca anyone explain  why did it work for right() but  not for left()?

Comment: No point in declaring `global` outside a function and fix your indentation

Comment: use `global box` inside your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global` is used **inside** the function, not out side.

So at the top of your file you can do

```
box = []
```

and inside your function:

```
global box
# now change box the way you want
```

Answer (score 7):

You must declare it global **inside** the function, not outside. Module level variables are always global:

```
box = ...    

def left():
    global box  # unnecessary, if not assigned a value
    box1 = [box[i][::-1] for i in range(4)]

def foo():
    global box  # necessary, otherwise box is local
    box = bar
```

The global declaration is unnecessary, as you are only using the variable and not assigning it a new value. It i therefore considered global by default.
See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.